# Harmonic Progression Summ Using Only MPI in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

Hi all I'm new to Parallel computing in C++. I want to parallelized the Harmonic Progression Sum in C++ only using MPI (Nothing else). Can you guys give me a proper starting point.

I have no idea where to start and how to convert it in Parallel code.

```
'#include <iostream>
 #include <sstream>

 using namespace std;

 void sum(char* output, const long unsigned int d, const long unsigned int n) 
 {
    long unsigned int digits[d + 11];
    for (long unsigned int digit = 0; digit < d + 11; ++digit) 
    {
        digits[digit] = 0;
    }
    for (long unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
    {
        long unsigned int remainder = 1;
        for (long unsigned int digit = 0; digit < d + 11 && remainder; ++digit)
    {
            long unsigned int div = remainder / i;
            long unsigned int mod = remainder % i;
            digits[digit] += div;
            remainder = mod * 10;
    }
    }
    for (long unsigned int i = d + 11 - 1; i > 0; --i) 
    {
        digits[i - 1] += digits[i] / 10;
        digits[i] %= 10;
    }
    if (digits[d + 1] >= 5) 
    {
        ++digits[d];
    }
    for (long unsigned int i = d; i > 0; --i) 
    {
        digits[i - 1] += digits[i] / 10;
        digits[i] %= 10;
    }
    stringstream stringstreamA;
    stringstreamA << digits[0] << ".";
    for (long unsigned int i = 1; i <= d; ++i) 
    {
        stringstreamA << digits[i];
    }
    stringstreamA << '\0';
    string stringA = stringstreamA.str();
    stringA.copy(output, stringA.size());
}

int main() {

    long unsigned int d, n;

    cin >> d >> n;

    char output[d + 10]; // extra precision due to possible error

    sum(output, d, n);

    cout << output << endl;

    return 0;
}'
```

Thanks
Kind Regards

Comment: Why do you want it to be parallel? If you want it to be faster, the first step is figuring out which parts are taking the longest - in other words, **profile your code**. However, by the looks of it, all your loop iterations carry significant dependencies so making them parallel might be difficult.

Comment: A proper starting point is some good book about MPI.